# C# Linq-to-XML on XCCDF

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to parse out information from a XCCDF output file but my Linq-to-Xml queries keep returning empty. Here are some of the ones I've tried to this point:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(s);
IEnumerable<XElement> findings = xelement.Elements();
XNamespace ns = "http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1";

var findingDetails = from f in findings.Descendants(ns + "Benchmark")
                     select new
                     {
                         title = f.Element("title").Value            
                     };

foreach (var fd in findingDetails)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fd.ToString());
}
```

I also tried:

```
var findingDetails = from f in findings.Descendants(ns + "Benchmark")
                     select f;

var findingDetails = from f in findings.Descendants("Benchmark")
                     select new
                     {
                         title = f.Element("title").Value             
                     };

var findingDetails = from f in findings.Elements(ns + "Benchmark")
                     select new
                     {
                         title = f.Element("title").Value             
                     };

var findingDetails = from f in findings.Elements(ns + "Benchmark")
                     select f;
```

Here is a condensed version of the xccdf.xml file. Based on this version how would I get the title "Red Hat..." (line 5) and the title "daemon umask" (line 19)? (I do understand that my examples above do not attempt to get this data, I had to break it down to just trying to get anything...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<cdf:Benchmark style="SCAP_1.1" resolved="1" id="RHEL_6_STIG" xsi:schemaLocation="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/xccdf-1.1.4.xsd http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0 http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.2/cpe-dictionary_2.2.xsd" xmlns:cdf="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1" xmlns:cpe="http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <cdf:status date="2016-04-22">accepted</cdf:status>
  <cdf:title>Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Security Technical Implementation Guide</cdf:title>
  <cdf:description>The Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Security Technical Implementation Guide (STIG) is published as a tool to improve the security of Department of Defense (DoD) information systems.  Comments or proposed revisions to this document should be sent via e-mail to the following address: disa.stig_spt@mail.mil.</cdf:description>
  <cdf:notice id="terms-of-use"></cdf:notice>
  <cdf:reference href="http://iase.disa.mil">
        <dc:publisher>DISA</dc:publisher>
        <dc:source>STIG.DOD.MIL</dc:source>
  </cdf:reference>
  <cdf:plain-text id="release-info">Release: 11 Benchmark Date: 22 Apr 2016</cdf:plain-text>
  <cdf:platform idref="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:6"></cdf:platform>
  <cdf:version>1</cdf:version>
  <cdf:Profile id="MAC-1_Classified">
        <cdf:title>I - Mission Critical Classified</cdf:title>            
  </cdf:Profile>
  <cdf:Value id="var_umask_for_daemons">
        <cdf:title>daemon umask</cdf:title>
        <cdf:description>Enter umask for daemons</cdf:description>
        <cdf:value>022</cdf:value>
        <cdf:value selector="022">022</cdf:value>
        <cdf:value selector="027">027</cdf:value>
  </cdf:Value>
</cdf:Benchmark>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `Benchmark` *and* `title` have the namespace `http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1`, so you need to use this if you're going to query for `title`.

Secondly, you parse using `XElement.Parse`, so the result is an element representing the `Benchmark` element.  You then get its child elements (`status` to `Value`).  Then you search for descendants of any of those called `Benchmark` - you're not going to find any, as `Benchmark` was where you started.

This should work:

```
var element = XElement.Load(s);

var findingDetails = new
{
    title = (string)element.Element(ns + "title")
};
```

Alternatively, load as a document:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(s);

var findingDetails =
    from benchmark in doc.Descendants(ns + "Benchmark")
    select new
    {
        title = (string)benchmark.Element(ns + "title")
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had thought I one point last night I tried something along these lines, but must have missed something.

Answer (score 2):

Try following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ProgrammingBasics
{
    class Exercise
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Benchmark").Select(y => new
            {
                title = (string)y.Elements().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "title").FirstOrDefault()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: still null, even when I added the namespace

Comment: The code works with the xml posted.  I fully tested.  Namespaces is not needed and could cause code to fail.